# Cannot query multi best match columns across rows in ElasticSearch 8.12.2

Tags: elasticsearch

Q: What is my goal?

A: Need a way to search best match columns across many rows.

Q: Can you explain with more details?

A: Suppose I have following data:

| ID | Key A | Key B | Key C | Val A | Val B | Val C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | b* | c* | va0 | NULL | vc0 |
| 2 | a* | bcd | c* | NULL | vb1 | vc1 |

In my circumanstance, I have a score function that will calculate best match values. For a given condition keys as: `Key A = abc`, `Key B = bcd` and `Key C = cde`, then I need to query the best match values as:

`Val A = va0`, `Val B = vb1` and `Val C = vc1`(a little special as following).

As as conclusion, suppose our score function is:

- When same: `2*i` (`i` is the position index starts from `1`)
- When pattern match: `1+i`
- When value is NULL, not match

With `Key A = abc`, `Key B = bcd` and `Key C = cde`, for row 1(`ID=1`):

`Key A` is exactly match, `Key B` is pattern match, `Key C` is pattern match too but the longer match with larger index is prior, the weight is `weight1 = 2*1 + (1+2) + 1+3 = 9`.

With the same algorithm, for row 2(`ID=2`), the weight is `weight2 = (1+1) + 2(1+2) + 1+3 = 12`.

For `Val A`, row 2 is NULL, then we got `va0` from row 1, for `Val B` row 1 is NULL then we got `vb1` from row 2. However for `Val C`, since `weight2 > weight1` then we got `vc1`.

That's why we got `Val A = va0`, `Val B = vb1` and `Val C = vc1`.

Further more, for a entire row to find the highest score row is clear(for the given data and query conditions row 2 is expected), but for column-level highest score match would be a problem.

---

Maybe we could search columns one-by-one, but if there are more than 100 columns this solution will die and it's not acceptable. BTW, any version of ElasticSearch is fine. We are using latest
`8.12.2` for testing purpose. We are in POC phase, and any solution will be appriciate and we are glad to do any test about that.

1. We tried to index entire rows and query the row has highest score with custom score function, it works and the solution is easy to know.
2. We read the manual and know `bulk query` API might be work but our columns could be ~5k it cannot work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

I re-organize your data:

1. Now document is a column with key and value
2. I replace the `NULL` values with new manually. You can program it
3. I couldn’t realize `wildcard` matching. So I replace it with `startsWith` checking

Mapping

```
PUT /key_matches
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "weight": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "pattern_values": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "pattern": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "score": {
                        "type": "double"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documents

```
PUT /key_matches/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"key":"A","weight":1,"pattern_values":[{"id":1,"pattern":"abc","value":"va0","score":0},{"id":2,"pattern":"a","value":"va0","score":0}]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"key":"B","weight":2,"pattern_values":[{"id":1,"pattern":"b","value":"vb1","score":0},{"id":2,"pattern":"bcd","value":"vb1","score":0}]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"key":"C","weight":3,"pattern_values":[{"id":1,"pattern":"c","value":"vc0","score":0},{"id":2,"pattern":"c","value":"vc1","score":0}]}
```

## Pass #1. Score calculation

`update_by_query` calculates a score for every nested `pattern_values` object. Source values are set in script `params`. You can `reindex` instead of updating

```
POST /key_matches/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
            def patternValues = ctx._source.pattern_values;
            List strings = params.strings;

            // calculate score
            String key = ctx._source.key;
            String string = "";
            for (str in strings) {
                if (str.containsKey(key)) {
                    string = str[key];
                }
            }
            
            int weigth = ctx._source.weight;

            for (patternValue in patternValues) {
                String pattern = patternValue.pattern;
                
                if (string.equals(pattern)) {
                    patternValue.score = 2 * weigth;
                } else if (string.startsWith(pattern)) {
                    patternValue.score = 1 + weigth;
                } else {
                    patternValue.score = 0;
                }
            }
        """,
        "params": {
            "strings": [{"A": "abc"}, {"B": "bcd"}, {"C": "cde"}]
        }
    }
}
```

## Pass #2. Total Score Calculation

Aggregation query

```
GET /key_matches/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "aggs": {
    "inside_pattern_values": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "pattern_values"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "pattern_values.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_score": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "pattern_values.score"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "inside_pattern_values" : {
      "doc_count" : 6,
      "by_id" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : 1,
            "doc_count" : 3,
            "total_score" : {
              "value" : 9.0
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : 2,
            "doc_count" : 3,
            "total_score" : {
              "value" : 10.0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Maximum total score is for id 2. Your calculation is wrong. Please, check

## Pass #3. Values extraction

Use id 2 in a following query (the `value` parameter)

```
GET /key_matches/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.inner_hits.pattern_values.hits.hits._source
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "pattern_values",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "pattern_values.id": {
                        "value": "2"
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Response contains expected values

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "inner_hits" : {
                    "pattern_values" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "score" : 2,
                                        "pattern" : "a",
                                        "id" : 2,
                                        "value" : "va0"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "inner_hits" : {
                    "pattern_values" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "score" : 4,
                                        "pattern" : "bcd",
                                        "id" : 2,
                                        "value" : "vb1"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "inner_hits" : {
                    "pattern_values" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "score" : 4,
                                        "pattern" : "c",
                                        "id" : 2,
                                        "value" : "vc1"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems a lot of work to do, I'm appreciate and going to verify its result and post any additional information. Thanks a lot!